# Tengo un error de control de formato en C# Excepción producida: 'System.FormatException' en mscorlib.dll

Tags: c#, ms-access

Tengo el error:

> "La cadena de entrada no tiene el formato correcto"

Al momento de tocar click en el botón para enviar los datos a la tabla de Access.

```
private void btnCrearReporte_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       
       try
       {
           var conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["NOC_C_.Properties.Settings.old_noc_databaseConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
           using (OleDbConnection Conector = new OleDbConnection(conString))
           {
               Conector.Open();
              // (fuente_reporte, fecha_incidente, fecha_notificacion, sitio_equipo, evento, tipo_evento, detalle_evento, tipo_trabajo, agente_monitoreo, encargado_ly)
               string query = "INSERT INTO reporte (fuente_reporte, fecha_incidente, fecha_notificacion, sitio_equipo, evento, tipo_evento, detalle_evento, tipo_trabajo, agente_monitoreo, encargado_ly)  VALUES (@fuente_reporte, @fecha_incidente, @fecha_notificacion, @sitio_equipo, @evento, @tipo_evento, @detalle_evento, @tipo_trabajo, @agente_monitoreo,@encargado_ly);";                   
               OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, Conector);
        
               cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fuente_reporte", CMBMedioDeReporte.SelectedItem);
               cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fecha_incidente", DateIncidente.Value.ToString("dd/mm/aaaa hh:mm:ss"));
               cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fecha_notificacion", DateNotificacion.Value.ToString("dd/mm/aaaa hh:mm:ss"));
               cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sitio_equipo", Int32.Parse(CMBEquipoFrm.SelectedValue.ToString()));
               cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@evento", CMBTituloFrm.SelectedItem);
               cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tipo_evento", Int32.Parse(CMBTipoFrm.SelectedValue.ToString()));
               cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@detalle_evento", txtDetalle.Text);
               cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tipo_trabajo", CMBTipoDeTrabajo.SelectedItem);
               cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@agente_monitoreo", Int32.Parse(CMBAgenteDeMonitoreo.SelectedValue.ToString()));
               cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@encargado_ly", Int32.Parse(CMBEncargadoLYFrm.SelectedValue.ToString()));
               cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
           
             
           }
          
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
       }
   }
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Y cual seria el problema en todo ese codigo??? que error recibis??

Comment: Cual es el error??

Comment: El error es la cadena de entrada no es la correcta.

Comment: El error ***podría*** darse en la concatenación de tu cadena de texto. No estás dejando espacio entre `)` y `Values`. Al concatenar ambas cadenas esta parte quedaría: `...,encargado_ly)Values (...`, tampoco estás dejando espacio entre el nombre de la tabla y los nombres de los campos en los que vas a hacer la inserción. Revisa que tu cadena preparada tenga el formato adecuado. Y por favor, copia y pega el error que dices tener, porque no se ve en la pregunta y aquí estamos adivinando, lo cual no es lo ideal. Por favor haz el [tour] y lee [ask].

Comment: Es al momento de envíar los datos al Access me tira el error de "La cadena de entrada no tiene el formato correcto" hice los cambios que me recomendo, pero sigue igual.

Comment: y cuando haces debug, como queda la cadena??? porque puede tener mas errores todavia...

Comment: Es el único error que me da

Comment: usa el boton [edit] y aclara bien los cambios que hiciste. La cadena esta mal porque le faltan espacios... ese es el problema...

Comment: Ya actualicé el código

Comment: Es probable que el error esté en uno de los `Int32.Parse` o `ToString`. No podemos adivinar cuál es el responsable. Por favor depura el código o deja que *crashee* para poder ver la línea en la que ocurre el error. Por ejemplo, [así](https://tio.run/##XYuxCsIwEEDn5ivOTi1of6Cji4NCwaGDOBxpCAdpDu6ugki/PQZH3/re83ryLKGUTSlHuL/Vwjo6n1AVJuEouMLHNWpo5OHFtMANKXdqUofHE1Ci9jWBPyjbMKFo6Nq2H13TnDkrpzDMQhaulKu4hJT4CDNLWg6/and7KV8). También podrías obtener la línea [así](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3329072)

Comment: Ya logre resolver el error anterior ahora tengo "La operación de múltiples paso de OLE DB generó errores."

Comment: Al momento de ingresar los datos desde C# a Access no me actualiza la tabla en Access, pero tampoco me da error.